# Laravel 8: Test MainClassTest from a ChildClassTest

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

How to test the MainClassTest Methods from a ChildClassTest extending it, since the child class will perform the same test scenarios but given with different data

Sample of code

```
 <?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Modules;

use Tests\TestCase;

class BaseControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_common_method_for_each_child()
    {
        // process
    }

}


<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Modules;

use Tests\TestCase;

class ChildControllerTest extends BaseControllerTest {

    public function test_unique_method() {
        // process
    }

}


<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Modules;

use Tests\TestCase;

class Child1ControllerTest extends BaseControllerTest {

    public function test_unique_method() {
        // process
    }

}
```

So when  run the php artisan test, should see a list of test

```
ChildControllerTest->test_common_method_for_each_child
ChildControllerTest->test_unique_method

Child1ControllerTest->test_common_method_for_each_child
Child1ControllerTest->test_unique_method
```

Comment: If you show us real code/scenario, it would be easier to help you. I am confused why you want to test it this way, as your `main`/`base` class (real class, not testing class) should be tested and then you can test your extension classes... so it could make no sense to extend from a test class and repeat the exact same tests with different data. Also you can use [`@dataProvider`s](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit-data-providers-examples-datatest-php) to send different data to the same test instead of copy-pasting the test. Share info

Answer (score 0):

The tests inside the parent will be ran when you'll run your child class tests, what you did should already work.

*If that's not the case, can you edit your question with the PHPUnit command you are running and its output?*

However, you should make your base class `abstract`:

```php
abstract class BaseControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_common_method_for_each_child()
    {
        // process
    }

}
```

If you don't do this, this class will also be called alone, out of the context of a child, during the test suite (which doesn't seem to be what your goal).

Comment: can you arrange to run first the parent class test scenario followed by child class test?